Cut up overlapping polygons in a gdb using terra or sf
I have a massive gdb of lots of polygons, many of them overlapping (sometimes partial overlaps and sometimes full overlaps). The polygons represent landscape treatments with different attributes I'd like to retain (e.g. treatment type, treatment year). Ultimately I would like to end up with either a  raster or a layer of vectors with no overlap, and all of the pertinent attributes retained for each pixel or polygon. I would like to process this data in R, ideally using either the terra or sf package (both of which I'm new to).
Here's an over-simplified image to illustrate where I'm hoping to get if I use a vector-approach. Say I start with three polygons: an orange treatment that occurred in 2010, a yellow treatment that occurred in 2010 , and a blue treatment that occurred in 2016.
Example illustration:
In this case, I want to end up with 9 distinct polygons with these example attributes retained:
1: orange, 2010
2: orange + yellow, 2010
3: blue + orange + yellow, 2010 + 2016
4: orange + yellow, 2010
5: blue + orange, 2010 + 2016
6: blue + orange, 2010 + 2016
7: blue, 2016
8: yellow, 2010
9: orange, 2010
The real data I'm using is publicly available fuel treatment data from the USFS that can be found here: https://data.fs.usda.gov/geodata/edw/datasets.php?xmlKeyword=facts+common+attributes (I'm using subsets of Region 5 data- they are massive data sets).
I am having a hard time figuring out how to pose this question so please let me know how I can clarify this post to help you help me figure it out- thank you all!
From the two large datasets above, I crop
So far, I have looked into sf and terra intersection functions, but it seems using those wouldn't allow me to retain the attributes of all the overlapping polygons.
If anyone can suggest a solution to simply cut up the polygons along any intersecting lines (so in the above example, I'd end up with one polygon "1" with attributes orange, 2010; two identically shaped polygon "2"- one with attributes orange, 2010 and one with attributes yellow, 2010, etc.), I can go from there and extract the gdb's attributes and merge the treatment attributes into strings and then merge the attributes back with the spatial data and retain only one version of each polygon.  This is my preferred solution since it would allow me the greatest control over maintain attribute data.
Another  idea is to rasterize all of my data and have a band for each treatment type or each year. But I don't know how to execute this solution and I can't think of how I could do it without losing data in cases where, on a single pixel, multiple types of treatments occur in the same year or the same type of treatment occurs in multiple years.
Feeling very lost in the sauce on this problem. Any tips or suggestions are greatly appreciated! Thank you all!

With sf you can use self-st_intersection(), result includes origins attribute, a list column that you can use to gather all origin features; though you'd need to work with it yourself, i.e. collect origin colours into a single string per feature or years into another list column, for example.
Using sf's nc Shapefile as an example here:
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.2, GDAL 3.6.2, PROJ 9.2.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(mapview)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# example dataset from sf package
nc <- 
  read_sf(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) |>
  # transform to NAD83(2011) for st_intersection()
  st_transform(6542) 

set.seed(42)  
# 10 random polygons and 50km buffer, some of those will probably overlap
nc_sample_buff <- nc[sample(1:100, 10),] |> st_buffer(50000)
mapview(nc_sample_buff[,"NAME"])


nc_sample_buff
#> Simple feature collection with 10 features and 14 fields
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 330408.1 ymin: -35243.19 xmax: 806324.9 ymax: 349425.5
#> Projected CRS: NAD83(2011) / North Carolina
#> # A tibble: 10 × 15
#>     AREA PERIMETER CNTY_ CNTY_ID NAME  FIPS  FIPSNO CRESS_ID BIR74 SID74 NWBIR74
#>  * <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <dbl>    <int> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 0.094      1.31  1979    1979 Wils… 37195  37195       98  3702    11    1827
#>  2 0.078      1.38  2034    2034 Linc… 37109  37109       55  2216     8     302
#>  3 0.108      1.48  1900    1900 Fors… 37067  37067       34 11858    10    3919
#>  4 0.104      1.55  2065    2065 Leno… 37107  37107       54  3589    10    1826
#>  5 0.199      1.98  1874    1874 Wilk… 37193  37193       97  3146     4     200
#>  6 0.212      2.02  2241    2241 Brun… 37019  37019       10  2181     5     659
#>  7 0.201      1.80  1968    1968 Rand… 37151  37151       76  4456     7     384
#>  8 0.128      1.55  1897    1897 Fran… 37069  37069       35  1399     2     736
#>  9 0.103      1.46  2045    2045 Stan… 37167  37167       84  2356     5     370
#> 10 0.121      1.86  2107    2107 Rich… 37153  37153       77  2756     4    1043
#> # ℹ 4 more variables: BIR79 <dbl>, SID79 <dbl>, NWBIR79 <dbl>,
#> #   geometry <POLYGON [m]>


nc_x <- st_intersection(nc_sample_buff)
# original attributes, n.overlaps and alist column of origins 
# (as indices/row numbers of original dataset)
nc_x
#> Simple feature collection with 38 features and 16 fields
#> Geometry type: GEOMETRY
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 330408.1 ymin: -35243.19 xmax: 806324.9 ymax: 349425.5
#> Projected CRS: NAD83(2011) / North Carolina
#> # A tibble: 38 × 17
#>     AREA PERIMETER CNTY_ CNTY_ID NAME  FIPS  FIPSNO CRESS_ID BIR74 SID74 NWBIR74
#>    <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <dbl>    <int> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 0.094      1.31  1979    1979 Wils… 37195  37195       98  3702    11    1827
#>  2 0.078      1.38  2034    2034 Linc… 37109  37109       55  2216     8     302
#>  3 0.078      1.38  2034    2034 Linc… 37109  37109       55  2216     8     302
#>  4 0.108      1.48  1900    1900 Fors… 37067  37067       34 11858    10    3919
#>  5 0.094      1.31  1979    1979 Wils… 37195  37195       98  3702    11    1827
#>  6 0.104      1.55  2065    2065 Leno… 37107  37107       54  3589    10    1826
#>  7 0.078      1.38  2034    2034 Linc… 37109  37109       55  2216     8     302
#>  8 0.078      1.38  2034    2034 Linc… 37109  37109       55  2216     8     302
#>  9 0.108      1.48  1900    1900 Fors… 37067  37067       34 11858    10    3919
#> 10 0.199      1.98  1874    1874 Wilk… 37193  37193       97  3146     4     200
#> # ℹ 28 more rows
#> # ℹ 6 more variables: BIR79 <dbl>, SID79 <dbl>, NWBIR79 <dbl>,
#> #   n.overlaps <int>, origins <list>, geometry <GEOMETRY [m]>

Top-5 sections with most overlaps:
nc_max_overlaps <-
  nc_x[,c("NAME","n.overlaps", "origins")] |> 
  slice_max(n.overlaps, n = 5) |>
  tibble::rownames_to_column("row_id") |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(origins = paste(origins, collapse = ",")) |>
  ungroup()
nc_max_overlaps
#> Simple feature collection with 7 features and 4 fields
#> Geometry type: GEOMETRY
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 445714.2 ymin: 161478.5 xmax: 541690.2 ymax: 244279.7
#> Projected CRS: NAD83(2011) / North Carolina
#> # A tibble: 7 × 5
#>   row_id NAME    n.overlaps origins                                     geometry
#>   <chr>  <chr>        <int> <chr>                                 <GEOMETRY [m]>
#> 1 1      Lincoln          5 2,3,5,7,9 POLYGON ((467901.5 235308.3, 469692.1 233…
#> 2 2      Lincoln          4 2,3,5,7   POLYGON ((467901.5 235308.3, 466037.1 237…
#> 3 3      Lincoln          4 2,3,7,9   GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (LINESTRING (476770.8 …
#> 4 4      Lincoln          4 2,3,5,9   POLYGON ((463943.7 212881.9, 461795.7 211…
#> 5 5      Forsyth          4 3,5,7,9   POLYGON ((488329.2 242544.6, 487507.2 240…
#> 6 6      Forsyth          4 3,7,9,10  POLYGON ((540411.5 207130.5, 538057.9 205…
#> 7 7      Lincoln          4 2,7,9,10  POLYGON ((483125.3 194763.8, 483249.3 193…

Using origins lists to collect attributes from source dataset:
# using origins lists:
nc_x_attr_comb <-
  nc_x[,c("NAME", "BIR74", "origins", "n.overlaps")] |>
  slice_max(n.overlaps, n = 5) |>
  mutate(
    # use origins values for subsetting values from original frame (nc_sample_buff)
    origin_names = map_chr(origins, \(idx) nc_sample_buff$NAME[idx] |> paste(collapse = "::")),
    # or perhaps create another list column
    origin_bir74_lst = map(origins, \(idx) nc_sample_buff$BIR74[idx]),
    .after = 1)

# as.data.frame to show list content
nc_x_attr_comb |> as.data.frame() 
#>      NAME                               origin_names
#> 1 Lincoln Lincoln::Forsyth::Wilkes::Randolph::Stanly
#> 2 Lincoln         Lincoln::Forsyth::Wilkes::Randolph
#> 3 Lincoln         Lincoln::Forsyth::Randolph::Stanly
#> 4 Lincoln           Lincoln::Forsyth::Wilkes::Stanly
#> 5 Forsyth          Forsyth::Wilkes::Randolph::Stanly
#> 6 Forsyth        Forsyth::Randolph::Stanly::Richmond
#> 7 Lincoln        Lincoln::Randolph::Stanly::Richmond
#>                origin_bir74_lst BIR74       origins n.overlaps
#> 1 2216, 11858, 3146, 4456, 2356  2216 2, 3, 5, 7, 9          5
#> 2       2216, 11858, 3146, 4456  2216    2, 3, 5, 7          4
#> 3       2216, 11858, 4456, 2356  2216    2, 3, 7, 9          4
#> 4       2216, 11858, 3146, 2356  2216    2, 3, 5, 9          4
#> 5       11858, 3146, 4456, 2356 11858    3, 5, 7, 9          4
#> 6       11858, 4456, 2356, 2756 11858   3, 7, 9, 10          4
#> 7        2216, 4456, 2356, 2756  2216   2, 7, 9, 10          4


Thank you @margusl! This does seem like it will be the tidiest solution to my problem. A couple things: I am running into a "GEOS exception" error I can't seem to fix when I try to run the "x_int <- st_intersection(x)" step. I tried correcting invalid geometries (10 invalid out of 1272 geometries in the gdb I'm testing this on) and checking for self-intersections (there seemed to be none). I don't really know what "self-intersections" means as there are intersecting polygons and are spatially identical polygons in this data. Do you know how I can fix the "GEOS exception" error?

Is it the same region 5 gdb? Did you also check those polygons with some other tool, e.g. topology checker in QGIS? Self-intersection usually refers to a knot or an envelope in a single feature.

terra::union can do that. I do not know if is ideal for your purpose as it creates an attribute variable for each original polygon. If you have very many polygons that might not be ideal.
Example data
library(terra)
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
# create overlapping polygons
b <- buffer(v, 2000)

Solution
u <- union(b)

u
# class       : SpatVector 
# geometry    : polygons 
# dimensions  : 47, 13  (geometries, attributes)
# extent      : 5.726209, 6.546187, 49.42983, 50.19956  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
# names       :  id_1  id_2  id_3  id_4  id_5  id_6  id_7  id_8  id_9 id_10 (and 3 more)
# type        : <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>             
# values      :     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0             
#                   0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0             
#                   1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0

Illustration
u$sum <- rowSums(as.data.frame(u))
plot(u, "sum")

ids <- apply(as.data.frame(u), 1, \(i) paste(which(i==1), collapse=", "))
ids
# [1] "1"         "2"         "1, 2"      "3"         "2, 3"      "4"         "1, 4"      "2, 4"      "1, 2, 4"   "5"         "1, 5"      "2, 5"     
#[13] "1, 2, 5"   "3, 5"      "2, 3, 5"   "6"         "2, 6"      "7"         "8"         "6, 8"      "7, 8"      "9"         "3, 9"      "10"       
#[25] "7, 10"     "9, 10"     "11"        "7, 11"     "8, 11"     "7, 8, 11"  "9, 11"     "10, 11"    "7, 10, 11" "9, 10, 11" "12"        "2, 12"    
#[37] "3, 12"     "2, 3, 12"  "6, 12"     "2, 6, 12"  "8, 12"     "6, 8, 12"  "9, 12"     "3, 9, 12"  "11, 12"    "8, 11, 12" "9, 11, 12"

